# How to use SimplePie sort_items()? Getting static method error

Tags: sorting, simplepie

I'm trying to alpha sort a single feed. When I use SimplePie's sort_items() I get the following error:

*Fatal error: Cannot make static method SimplePie::sort_items() non static in class SimplePie_Custom_Sort...*

As a test, I copied the example code from SimplePie's documentation and ran that on its own, but the same error persists.
http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/sort_items

I'm using PHP 5.2.17 and everything is fine in the compatibility test. I've tried both SimplePie 1.3 and 1.3.1.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `SimplePie_Custom_Sort` class needs to declare `sort_items()` as static:

```
public static function sort_items($a, $b)
```

This is due to a change in SimplePie 1.3 from 1.2 thanks to PHP 5 support.